# How to add a menu to login form module in Joomla 1.7?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7, joomla-module

I am intrested in changing the joomla default Login module to show a menu as a greeting in the login module,
so that menu will contain links for profile management and stuff from that sort.

I have tried to add a module position inside the module (dawg!) 
But that went down the drain.

And i'm not intrested in adding manual links to pages because they might change.

Any ideas guys?

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code in login module template where you want to show the menu

```
$module = JModuleHelper::getModules('xxxx');
 // xxxx is any virtual position, no need to create it anywhere.
echo JModuleHelper::renderModule($module[0]);
```

and enable a menu module at position 'xxxx'.

I hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create a custom module to do that. There is no way to do it with the parameters you have given. You could use the module alternative layout to add in some links to the login module, but you can't add a menu to it without rewriting the entire module.